# WP7 gps emulator issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps

I have an issue using the GPS emulator provided by microsoft.
This is my code

```
public IGeoPositionWatcher<GeoCoordinate> Watcher { get; private set; }
public IObservable<GeoCoordinate> ObservableGeoCoordinate { get; set; }
private void InitializeGpsDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Watcher == null)
            {
                Watcher = new GpsEmulatorClient.GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            }

            ObservableGeoCoordinate = CreateObservableGeoPositionWatcher();

            Watcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Failed to initialize GPS device:{0}", ex.Message), "GPS Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
private IObservable<GeoCoordinate> CreateObservableGeoPositionWatcher()
    {
        var observable = Observable.FromEvent<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(
                            e => Watcher.PositionChanged += e,
                            e => Watcher.PositionChanged -= e
                            ).Select(e => e.EventArgs.Position.Location);

        return observable;
    }
```

After creating my IObservable object I use it this way:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeDefaults();
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var observable = GpsHelper.Instance.ObservableGeoCoordinate;
        observable
             .ObserveOnDispatcher()
             .Subscribe(OnPositionChanged);
    }

    private void OnPositionChanged(GeoCoordinate location)
    {
        Map.Center = location;
    }
```

But the event OnPositionChanged is never raised.
Anyone can suggest why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GPSEmulator running and still ...GPS status: NoData!

Try this!

GPSEmulator/MainWindow.xaml.cs/line: 391

```
string lat = currentPosition.X.ToString().Replace(",", "."); 
string lon = currentPosition.Y.ToString().Replace(",", "."); 
transmittedLocation = lat+","+lon;
```

Comment: In effect the Watcher status id always NoData. But I don't understand where you are suggesting to make write this code... maybe in the source code of GPSEmulator? Do you think this is an issue of the emulator?

Comment: You got it man! It was an bug of the GPS emulator! Maybe it's a problem derived from regional settings or something similar. Anyway, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you first subscribed the OnLoaded event in your View or Page constructor ?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Try to Start Watcher in your CreateObservableGeoPositionWatcher (just before returning observable). Observable object seems to be associated to Gps Start before subscription.

Comment: No way. Even with your suggestion the handler OnPositionChanged is never called. What the hell am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work :( I also tried not to use Reaction Extension and register the PositionChanged event handler for the Watcher object in the standard way in the OnLoaded method, but nothing seems to change. Simply no event is raised by the watcher...